# Drawing dynamic graphs in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following data

```
Name Date      Number_of_apples
-------------------------------
abc  1-1-2012  5
abc  2-1-2012  3
xyz  1-1-2012  4
xyz  2-1-2012  2
xyz  3-1-2012  6
```

I want to plot a 2D line graph in excel representing the above data.

Graph should contain `Date` in X axis and `Number of apples` in Y axis.

Example plot for name `abc` :

[image]

**Depending on selection of name, the graph should update to represent data for that name.**

Comment: You mean if I select `XYZ` then all the XYZ data is shown? Is the name field always grouped e.g. `XYZ` data is always together in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Some notes:

1. This code needs to be placed in a `Worksheet` module
2. To update the chart simply click the name in your `name` column e.g. 'xyz', 'abc' etc.
3. If no chart is present it creates one first and then subseqently updates that same chart

Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
        UpdateChart Target
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateChart(name As Range)
    Dim startRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim namerng As Range, data As Range, applechart As ChartObject

    Set namerng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)

    startRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(name.Value, namerng, 0)
    lastRow = startRow + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(namerng, name.Value) - 1

    On Error Resume Next
    Set applechart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("AppleChart")
    Set data = Range("B" & startRow & ":C" & lastRow)

    If Not applechart Is Nothing Then
        applechart.Activate
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=data
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).name = "AppleChart"
        ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=data
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit: How to set-up in Excel**

1. In Excel press `ALT` + `F11`. This opens the VBA editor
2. In the left hand project window click the worksheet where your data is held e.g. Sheet1
3. In the left hand dropdown select `Worksheet`
4. In the right hand dropdown select `SelectionChange`
5. Cut and paste the code

Note - I am assuming your data starts in column A. If not you'll need to amend the column references in the code yourself

Comment: It would be great if you could explain me the whole procedure of how to get this working. Sorry for asking more. I am very new to excel.

Comment: I have updated the answer. See `Edit: How to set-up in Excel`

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks so much :) Worked like a charm!